# Shiny datatable, filter columns by background color (as we have in excel)

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

How to filter out columns in shiny DT datatable based on cell color. Just like we have in excel.
[Need to filter the column with yellow color in background.]
Below is the code for cells with color:

```
input_data <- data.frame(Record_Status = c("Modified","NO","NO","Modified","NO","NO","Modified","NO","NO"),
                         Field_Changed = c("Brand,ratio","Gender","Name","ratio,Name,Gender","cost","Brand,cost","ratio,cost","cost","Name"),
                         Brand = c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27),
                         ratio = c (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                         cost = c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27),
                         Name = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                         Gender = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Build hidden logical columns for conditional formatting
dataCol_df <- ncol(input_data) 
dataColRng <- 3:dataCol_df
argColRng <- (dataCol_df + 1):(dataCol_df * 2 -2)

df <- sapply(1:ncol(input_data),function(i) ifelse(input_data[[1]]=="Modified" & 
                                                     str_detect(input_data[[2]], names(input_data)[i]),
                                                   "1","0"))
df <- df[,-c(1,2)]

input_data <- data.frame(input_data, df)


# Create Shiny Output
shinyApp(
  ui = 
    navbarPage("Testing",dataTableOutput('dt')),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt = DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(input_data,
                # Hide logical columns
                options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, 
                                                    targets=argColRng)))) %>% 
        # Format data columns based on the values of hidden logical columns
        formatStyle(columns = dataColRng,
                    valueColumns = argColRng,
                    backgroundColor = styleEqual(c('1', '0'), 
                                                 c("yellow", "white")))
    )}
)
```

[image]

Comment: please add an example here, so that we understand what you mean.

Comment: @wiebke I have added an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have more than I issue here. For me the shiny app is not running and I believe this might be due to a mixup what should be in the ui and what in the server function.
About your original question. You could use the library DT and color the cells you like. This is independent of your shiny app, however, I believe you can use this also in the app, once you have the app running without the coloring.

```
library(DT)
datatable(input_data) %>% formatStyle(
  'Brand', 'X1',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)
```